# Non-intrusively replacing a custom type with an expression tree

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, boost-proto

I'm trying to introduce lazy evaluation into an existing code project. The project core basically consists of a large amount of calculations using a custom type (it acts like a double but does additional work in the background).

Our goal is to introduce a lazy evaluation concept using boost proto in Order to optimize existing expressions.

Restrictions:

- The existing calculations can't be touched
- The type used is defined by a typedef, so replacing the type itself is possible

We tried to implement a simple proof of concept but didn't manage the code to behave as desired. This is what we got so far:

```
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::proto;

// The custom implemented Type
typedef std::complex<double> my_type;

// The Basic expression wrapper
template< typename Expr = proto::terminal< my_type >::type >
struct MyDoubleExpr
  : proto::extends< Expr, MyDoubleExpr< Expr >, proto::default_domain >
{
    typedef
        proto::extends< Expr, MyDoubleExpr< Expr >, proto::default_domain >
    base_type;

    MyDoubleExpr( Expr const &expr = Expr() )
      : base_type( expr )
    {}

  // Overloading of all Constructors supported by the custom type
  typedef typename proto::terminal< my_type >::type expr_type;
  MyDoubleExpr( double const &d)
    : base_type( expr_type::make(my_type(d)))
    {}

  // Lazy assignment is desired
    BOOST_PROTO_EXTENDS_USING_ASSIGN(MyDoubleExpr)

};

// unintrusively replace the existing type with
// the expression template
typedef MyDoubleExpr<> replaced_type;


int main() {

  replaced_type a = 2.0, b = 1.5;

  proto::default_context ctx;

  // The replaced type is created as template specialisation
  // proto::terminal< my_type >::type -> cannot store expressions
  replaced_type c;
  c = (a + b) * 2.0;
  std::cout << "c: " << proto::eval(c,ctx) << endl << endl;
  proto::display_expr(c);

  // Initialisation does not work directly ?
  //replaced_type d = a+b;

  // using auto works fine, so the expression basically works
  auto e = (a + b) * 2.0;
  std::cout << "e: " << proto::eval(e,ctx) << endl;
  proto::display_expr(e);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Our main problem is that we can't define a type which works with both literals and expressions alike. In this example, c is a Expression of type proto::terminal and ignores the assignment of the expression. When using auto to store the expression, it works fine. Also, direct initialization is not possible.

If i understand our problem correctly we would require two different types for expressions and literals, which is not possible because we can only change the existing type.

We also looked into other options, like using BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS(...) to make our custom type a terminal non-intrusively, but lazy assignment is not possible either.

So, our question is if we can achieve what we want or do we have to change the existing code to introduce lazy evaluation?

Thanks for your help,
Matthias`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [lazy vector example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.examples.lazy_vector) from Proto's docs. There is a `lazy_vector_expr` template for lazy vector expressions, and a `lazy_vector` template specifically for terminals (which inherits most of its implementation from `lazy_vector_expr`). `lazy_vector` defines a `+=` operator that accepts arbitrary lazy-vector expressions, evaluates them, and stores the result.

It sounds to me like you're doing something similar. But instead of `+=`, you are looking for ordinary assignment and converting construction. So define a template'd constructor and assignment operator. Something like (untested)...

```
template<typename XXX = proto::is_proto_expr> // hack, needed to for ADL
struct replaced_type_t
  : MyDoubleExpr< proto::terminal<double>::type > 
{
    replaced_type_t(double d = 0.0)
      : MyDoubleExpr< proto::terminal<double>::type >(
            proto::terminal<double>::type::make(d)
        )
    {}
    // Converting constructor
    template<typename OtherExpr>
    replaced_type_t(MyDoubleExpr<OtherExpr> const & e)
    {
        // Evaluate e, assign to *this
    }
    // Converting assignment
    template<typename OtherExpr>
    replaced_type_t& operator=(MyDoubleExpr<OtherExpr> const & e)
    {
        // Evaluate e, assign to *this
    }
};

typedef replaced_type_t<> replaced_type;
```

Incidentally, when you used `BOOST_PROTO_EXTENDS_USING_ASSIGN`, what you got was an overloaded assignment operator that building a bigger expression. So this:

```
replaced_type c;
c = (a + b) * 2.0;
```

... is going to have the unexciting effect of creating a temporary `MyDoubleExpr<>` containing an assignment node, and then throwing it away.

HTH!

Comment: thanks. Got it to work with minor changes (I had to use OtherExpr directly instead of MyDoubleExpr<OtherExpr> as assignment parameters). Evaluation and calculation works fine. The only problem is that this will eagerly calculate every expression. For better optimization options, it would be nice if an assignment does not evaluate an expression but stores it lazily.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stores it lazily". When do you want it to be evaluated?

Comment: In the best case, only when I call proto::eval(c,ctx) at the end of a program. Before that, any expression should be stored only. Our ideal usecase would be that we can build a single expression tree over the whole program (with a set of input parameters and a single result value), spanning over several calculations and function calls.

Comment: Building up an entire program as a gigantic expression template and evaluating it lazily is impractical, so you'll need to set your sights lower, or else give up on expression templates. With ETs, you must constrain yourself to what you can do in one expression ... basically, between semis. That can be a lot. Some EDSL's use the comma op in place of semis. That way, you can have assign ops that are lazy: `a=f(x),b=g(x),c=a*b;`. This gets difficult to manage. Another option: make your terminals nullary func objs that type-erase their (lazily computed) values. That costs an allocation, tho.